# how can I send coordinates to parse and save it as parse PFGeopoint

Tags: ios, parse-platform, coordinates, cllocation, parse-framework

How can i send coordinates to Parse fetched by CLLocation and save it there as PFGeoPoint's latitude and longitude?

I am able to get the coordinates from CLLocation and I want to send it to Parse. In Parse I have a column named "coordinates" of type PFGeoPoint which has two fields.Now I want to save the coordinates which I have got from CLLocation to Parse Column coordinates.
can anyone please help me with this?
I am new to iOS and Parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Convert CLLocation to PFGeoPoint

   ```
   //SWIFT
   let point = PFGeoPoint(location: currentLoc)

   //Obj-c
   [PFGeoPoint *point = PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLocation:(PF_NULLABLE CLLocation *)location];
   ```
2. Now save it.

   ```
   //SWIFT
   object["coordinates"] = point
   object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
     (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
     if (success) {
               // The object has been saved.
     } else {
               // There was a problem, check error.description
     }
   }

   //Obj-c
   object["coordinates"] = point;
   [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
     if (succeeded) {
       // The object has been saved.
     } else {
       // There was a problem, check error.description
     }
   }];
   ```

Comment: can you please post the answer once again in Objective -C I don't know about Swift. and thank you for the response

Comment: thank you for the answer but it's saying "[Error]: The object is too large -- should be less than 128 kB. (Code: 116, Version: 1.7.2)".

Comment: Not sure but there must be doing something else going on. The code I gave you should work. It comes from the parse.com doc.

Comment: it's saying that the object which I am sending is more than 128kb so it can't be saved any idea how to solve this? and is there any way to send only the coordinates not the whole object of CLLocation

Comment: This is another question man... I have no idea what else is in your object... You should ask a new question.