# How can I save locations(pins) to a parse server?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have an app that shows locations in a tableview that can be added via a button on a map. I have trouble saving these to parse (yes I know it is being retired but I have set up a new server that works exactly the same so consider it is parse) also note I have looked at this subject : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435362/how-can-i-send-coordinates-to-parse-and-save-it-as-parse-pfgeopoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435362/how-can-i-send-coordinates-to-parse-and-save-it-as-parse-pfgeopoint)t  and even if it looks pretty simple it still has me confused so here is my code in my tableview

```
var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

var activePlace = -1
```

and here is the code that ads a pin (in the map view controller )

```
 @IBAction func addSpot(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


        var newCoordinate2 = self.map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

        var location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate2.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate2.longitude)

        //title = "new address"

        //try change order start

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate2

        annotation.title = title


        annotation.coordinate = self.map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in


            var title = ""

            if (error == nil) {

                if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                    var subThouroughfare:String = ""
                    var thouroughfare:String = ""

                    if p.subThoroughfare != nil {

                        subThouroughfare = p.subThoroughfare!

                    }

                    if p.thoroughfare != nil {

                        thouroughfare = p.thoroughfare!

                    }

                    title = "\(subThouroughfare) \(thouroughfare)"


                }

            }

            if title == "" {

                title = "Added \(NSDate())"

            }

            places.append(["name":title,"lat":"\(newCoordinate2.latitude)","lon":"\(newCoordinate2.longitude)"])

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate2

            annotation.title = title

            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }

        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation);





        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
                     viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!{
            if(annotation is MKUserLocation){
                return nil;
            }

           // let pinView: Void = mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,reuseIdentifier:"MyIdentifier");
            return pinAnnotationView;


        }



    }
```

thank you for helping as I am new to using parse / external servers

EDIT: I have tried this:

```
    PFObject["geoPoint"] = PFGeoPoint(location: location)

    location[location] = activePlace
    location.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
        print("place has been saved")
    }
```

I get errors on the three lines 
1) instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'PFObject'
2) type 'CLLocation' has no subscript members
3) value of type CLLocation has no member 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock'

RE EDIT: I have tried this and get a warning saying 'code after return will never be executed' also it runs on the app but doesn't save

```
    let geoPoint = PFObject(className: "location")

    geoPoint["location"] = activePlace
    geoPoint.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
        print("place has been saved")
    }
```

Comment: you haven't explained what your code is doing wrong

Comment: It's not doing anything wrong but it is not uploading to parse. I just don't know how to add the locations I've got to parse @Wain

Comment: have you defined a PFObject which will hold your location / each location ?

Comment: No I haven't because I'm not sure what to put in the PFObject that would work with the code I already have and that would be compatible with parse , this is why I posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need something to contain your `PFGeoPoint`, and that thing needs to be a `PFObject`. In the parse back end you can create the table for this object and set it up with a reference to a geoPoint and whatever else you want. Now you can instantiate a `PFObject` for each new point with the class name of the table, set the reference to the geoPoint (with `pfObject["geoPoint"] = geoPoint`), save it (with `pfObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock...`) and you're done.

Comment: I tried something like this ( see edited question ) It doesn't seem to work but i'm sure I didn't do exactly what you meant

Comment: the `PFObject` instance and the `PFGeoPoint` instances are different. The `PFObject` is the owner and container into which the `PFGeoPoint` is stored. You have tried to make them the same thing but that won't work

Comment: I edited it the question again , this time I get a warning saying 'code after return will never be executed' and doesn't save but im sure it's better?

Comment: your code looks better, but you must have a `return` above that code somewhere to get the error and for it not to work